# Function Returning a NoneType in Python?

Tags: python, function, nonetype

Working on a Python project for CS1, and I have come accross a strange issue that neither I or my roomate can figure out. The general scope of the code is to fill in a grid of 0s with shapes of a certain size using numbers to fill the space, and we have to check along the way to make sure we arent putting shapes in places there there are already shapes. I have two functions here, both do virtually the same thing, but for whatever reason when falsechecker returns the list it returns it as a NoneType. Why is this happening?

```
def falseChecker(binList, r, c, size):
    sCheck = isSpaceFree(binList, r, c, size)
    if sCheck == True:
        for x in range(c, c+size):
            for y in range(r, r+size):
                binList[x][y] = size
        return binList
    else:
        c += 1
        if c > len(binList):
            c = 0
            r += 1
            if r > len(binList):
                return binList
        falseChecker(binList, r, c, size)





def iChecker(binList, blockList):
    r = 0
    c = 0
    for i in blockList:
        check = isSpaceFree(binList, r, c, i)
        if check == True:
            for x in range(c, c+i):
                for y in range(r, r+i):
                    binList[x][y] = i
            c += 1
            if c > len(binList):
                c = 0
                r += 1
                if r > len(binList):
                    return binList
        else:
            binList = falseChecker(binList, r, c, i)

    return binList

main()
```

Comment: @Everybody: Is there a canonical duplicate for the common "I wrote a recursive function but didn't return the value from one of the recursive calls" question?

Comment: As a side note, `if sCheck:` is better than `if sCheck == True:` in almost every situation (including this one).

Comment: @abarnert "almost"? Is there *any* situation where `== True` is preferred?

Comment: @lvc: Once upon a time, I was using a badly-designed package that wrapped up a C library with functions that returned `True` for success but a negative integer error code for failure. I wrote a module that wrapped all of the calls and checked `== True` else raised an exception with the number, to hide the horrible API from the rest of my code, with in a comment explaining what it was doing, and filed a bug against the package. (In case you're curious, the upstream fix was to return a tuple of True or False and 0 or a negative error code, which was slightly less horrible…)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the case where `sCheck == True` is false, you don't `return` anything. And in Python, a function that doesn't explicitly `return` anything returns `None`.

If you were trying to recursively call yourself and return the result, you wanted this:

```
return falseChecker(binList, r, c, size)
```

Answer (score 6):

The recursive line:

```
falseChecker(binList, r, c, size)
```

needs to be

```
return falseChecker(binList, r, c, size)
```

or the recursed function ends, and the outer function *keeps going* since it hasn't returned yet. It then finishes without returning, and so returns `None`.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `return` at the end of `falseChecker`:

```
def falseChecker(binList, r, c, size):
    sCheck = isSpaceFree(binList, r, c, size)
    if sCheck == True:
        for x in range(c, c+size):
            for y in range(r, r+size):
                binList[x][y] = size
        return binList
    else:
        c += 1
        if c > len(binList):
            c = 0
            r += 1
            if r > len(binList):
                 return binList

        #################################
        return falseChecker(binList, r, c, size)
        #################################
```

In Python, functions return `None` by default if they come to the end of themselves without returning.  Furthermore, when `falseChecker` is run for the first time, if `sCheck` is `False`, then it will execute the `else` block.  This code block doesn't contain a `return`.  Because of this, the ultimate return value of `falseChecker` will be `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same cuestion, taking some exercices beyond my duties =), I've modified some codes to learn how to use decorators:

```
def listPrime(f):    #list the prime numbers
    def wrapper(x):
        for n in range(x):
            if f(n):
                print(n, end = " ", flush=True)
        print()

@listPrime
def isprime(n = 0): #evaluate when a number is prime (true) or isn't
    if n<=1:
        return False
    for x in range(2,n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True

isprime(100)
```

but in this case the console throw me this error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable", printing the type of the object (function) isprime() in this situation it says that it is actually a <class 'NoneType'>, but when I erase the @listPrime decorator, this status changes to a <class 'function'>. Why is that?

I Know there is another form to run the code:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n<=1:
        return False
    for x in range(2,n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True

def listPrime(x):    #lista numeros primos
    for n in range(x):
        if isprime(n):
            print(n, end = " ", flush=True)
    print()

listPrime(200)
```

But I tried to modify it for the purpose of learning how to use decorators.

Comment: Ok, I did it by giving a return to the listPrime function "return wrapper" . but I still don't understand why the type of isprime change with a decorator.